# AngularJS - should the SEO URL be taken into account?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

I'm building an app in AngularJS and I was thinking about using SEO URLs. Currently my states are as follows:

article/page/:page - for a paginated listing of articles

article/:id - to view details of a single article

I thought about adding another state as follows:
article/:id/:seo

I would completely ignore the :seo state parameter, so no matter if the URL was
article/25/some-article-title or article/25/something-different, it would still display the exactly same article.

I would then simply link people to those URLs, but still ignoring the seo state parameter. It would only serve an informational purpose.

My question is if this is acceptable. All I found are high end javascript SEO frameworks on top of an already heavy framework. I don't need that. I just want a simple way to show people readable URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the canonical URL isset, the overall vanity URL matters little as the canonical one will be indexed.

A commercial example, ESPN do this all the time. Sometimes the URL conforms, sometime's it redirects to the correct page and if all else fails it just redirects to a search.

But no matter how many variations of the URL and how malformed it is, it takes away little, if anything, from the *indexed* content of the page.

However, if the ratio of total links to a url for a 301 redirect is overwhleming, it is indeed possible for the vanity url to appear in indexes despite it being a 301 redirect.

Again, ESPN as an example, searching the term `site:espn.com/billsimmons` will show an indexed page that will redirect to `http://search.espn.go.com/bill-simmons/`.

As long as you set the canonical URL, you should be fine.